# asp.net Dynamic Data Entities Site sorting rows

Tags: asp.net, entities, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am working on an admin area that is a Dynamic Data Entities site. My tables have an Int column called OrderID that is meant to be the displayed order for the Admin and front end of my site. Does the asp.net Dynamic Data site have anything built in the admin area for allowing the user to custom sort their rows e.g. up and down arrows that will change the orderid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such functionality from the box. But you may change display templates for some columns and use custom user control.